# JQuery.animate() moving divs at different speeds on some browsers

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I recently started using JQuery and created a little slider to display logos of website sponsors and such. It seemed to be working properly for me using Firefox. I decided to load up the site in Chrome and it behaves rather strange. The animation seems fine until the first div(the slider is split into two divs, so that the first can move to the end once it has completed it's pass through the masking div) enters the screen for the second(and each concurrent) pass. The first div seems to move more rapidly, and overtakes the second div. Any ideas what would cause this? It only seems to happen in Chrome and Safari. IE worked even!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var s1 = $("div[name=s1]");
var s2 = $("div[name=s2]");
var release = 0;
var speed = 75; //px per sec
var interval = 100; //milliseconds per animation
var origSpeed = speed;

function slide() {
    release = 1 - release;
    if (release == 0) {
        return;
    }
    distance = "+=" + (parseInt(s1.width(), 10) + parseInt(s2.width(), 10)) + "px";
    if ((-1 * parseInt(s1.css("left"), 10)) > parseInt(s1.width(), 10)) {
        s1.css({left: distance});
    }
    if ((-1 * parseInt(s2.css("left"), 10)) > (parseInt(s1.width(), 10) + parseInt(s2.width(), 10))) {
        s2.css({left: distance});
    }
    slide_again();
}

function slide_again() {
    $("div[id=slider]").animate({left: "-=" + interval * (speed / 1000) + "px"}, interval, "linear", slide);
}

    $("div[id=slider]").hover(function() {
    speed = 0;
    }, function() {
        speed = origSpeed;
    });

    slide();
});
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.racefactorygaming.com/test/slidertest.html)

Comment: You should never have two elements with the same `id`.  This is not valid markup.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've changed it to class rather than id. Unfortunately, no change in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation depends on timed interrupts.  There is no guarantee of exact timings, and so depending on implementation, the timing of your two sliders may diverge.

If you just use one slider element, you won't run into that issue.  It also simplifies the code quite a bit.  The way to do this is to replicate your slider elements (using jQuery) and then animate half the width (the pre-duped width) and start over:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var speed = 75; //px per sec

    // Get the width of the slider before you duplicate it
    var width = $('#slider').outerWidth();

    // Repeat the inner content by cloning and appending it to the end
    $('#slider').append($('#slider').children().clone());

    function slide() {
        // The duration takes into account the current position
        // in case you are starting from a hover-pause
        var curleft = $('#slider').position().left;
        var duration = (width+curleft) * 1000 / speed;
        $("#slider").animate({
            // Animate until original width slides off to left
            left: "-" + width + "px"
        }, duration, "linear", function() {
            // Reset to original position and start over
            $(this).css("left", "0px");
            slide();
        });
    }

    $("#slider").hover(function() {
        $('#slider').stop();
    }, function() {
        slide();
    });

    slide();
});
```

You can also change your hover to just do `.stop()` and `slide()` as long as you do a little extra math in your `slide()` call to see where you currently are.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Dxg6/

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this is what I was looking for!
Unfortunately, now I'm having an issue with Chrome calculating outerWidth() incorrectly.

Comment: Seems to work in the fiddle.  I read that there is a bug in Chrome where the order of loading css and javascript matter when getting `outerWidth`.  Try loading your CSS first and then your script.

Comment: If your width won't change a lot, you can always hard code it as a temporary workaround.  I think it is 2164.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The width would only change when adding/removing images. Or if the height is changed. It seems that Chrome is only calculating the width of the first child of "#slider" rather than the entire div.

Then again. Looking at this differently. It appears that chrome wont calculate the width of the images. I tried adding the width's of the images separately, and come up with 200 px and 10 images. Each image has a 20px margin, so Chrome is ONLY calculating the margin with outerWidth(true). Could it be that Chrome can't calculate the width of an image if it isn't directly set?

Comment: Did you update your html?  Because I am looking at your example page and you updated the javascript, but your html is still the same.  You need to merge both `slider` divs into one div and change it back to `id="slider"`.  Also, your script still says `$('div[id=slider]')`, when it should say `$('#slider')`.

Comment: Yes, I did. Just not on the slidertest.html page. I actually have it on the bottom of the homepage [here](http://racefactorygaming.com/). I have edited the [slidertest page](http://racefactorygaming.com/test/slidertest.html) as well now. It is puzzling that it works fine in jsfiddle on both browsers, but not on my site.

Comment: Aha!  I figured it out...  You are using `$(document).ready(...`, which doesn't wait for all images to load, which means the widths aren't defined yet.  If you change it to `$(window).ready(...`, it will work!  It works in jsFiddle, because jsFiddle wraps all of the javascript in `$(window).load()`

Comment: Oh thank you so much! That seemed to do it. It's funny, I tried changing that when mine wasn't working previously, but it wasn't something I thought to check after changing to the single div. Anywho, it works now! Though I think you meant "change it to `$(window).load()`" :) Thanks for the help!